# Adminhtml - white grid - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, adminhtml, grid, best-practice

I'm creating some menu admin and i have a container grid with buttons, but not a grid,  logically this means that I don't load my block but I dont find the issue, i tried to get the class of a block and i can get it `string(28) "Sd_Menu_Block_Adminhtml_Menu"`:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('sd_menu/adminhtml_menu');
var_dump(get_class($block)); //get class of block
```

[image]

*Here is a full code, and if you see somethings wrong somewhere, the corrections are welcome:*

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml.Menu.php**

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Block_Adminhtml_Menu extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container{

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->_blockGroup     = 'sd_menu';
    $this->_controller     = 'adminhtml_menu';
    $this->_headerText     = $this->__('Gérer le Menu');
    $this->_addButtonLabel = $this->__('Ajouter');
    parent::__construct();
  }

}
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml/Menu/Grid.php**

```
<?php

class Sd_Menu_Block_Adminhtml_Menu_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('menuGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('menu/menu')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
          'header'    => $this->__('Id'),
          'align'     =>'right',
          'width'     => '10px',
          'index'     => 'id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('name', array(
          'header'    => $this->__('Nom'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'index'     => 'name',
          'width'     => '50px',
        ));


        $this->addColumn('address', array(
            'header'    => $this->__('Adresse'),
            'width'     => '150px',
            'index'     => 'content',
        ));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/controllers/Adminhtml/MenuController.php**

```
<?php

class Sd_Menu_Adminhtml_MenuController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('Menu 1')
            ->_title($this->__('Submenu1')); // for title
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function listAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('Menu 1')
            ->_title($this->__('Submenu2')); //for title
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Model/Menu.php**

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Model_Menu extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{

    /**
     * Le constructeur
     */
    public function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('menu/menu');
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Model/Resource/Menu.php**

```
<?php

class Sd_Menu_Model_Resource_Menu extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('menu/menu', 'entity_id');
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Model/Resource/Menu/Collection.php**

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Model_Resource_Menu_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('menu/menu');
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sd_Menu>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Sd_Menu>
    </modules>
    <global>

        <helpers>
            <sd_menu>
                <class>Sd_Menu_Helper</class>
            </sd_menu>
        </helpers>

        <blocks>
            <sd_menu>
                <class>Sd_Menu_Block</class>
            </sd_menu>
        </blocks>

        <models>
            <menu>
                <class>Sd_Menu_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>menu_resource</resourceModel> //the corercted add
            </menu>
            <menu_resource>
                <class>Sd_Menu_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <menu>
                        <table>wlc_sd_menu</table>
                    </menu>
                </entities>
            </menu_resource>
        </models>

        <resources>
            <menu_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Sd_Menu</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </menu_setup>
        </resources>

    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <sd_menu before="Mage_Adminhtml">Sd_Menu_Adminhtml</sd_menu>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <sd_menu>
                    <file>sd_menu.xml</file>
                </sd_menu>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/etc/adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <menu1 module="sd_menu" translate="title">
            <title>Menu 1</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <item1 module="sd_menu" translate="title">
                    <title>Submenu 1</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/menu/index</action>
                </item1>
                <item2 module="sd_menu" translate="title">
                    <title>Submenu 2</title>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/menu/list</action>
                </item2>
            </children>
        </menu1>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <menu1 translate="title" module="sd_menu">
                        <title>My Controller</title>
                        <sort_order>-100</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <item1 translate="title">
                                <title>Index Action</title>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            </item1>
                            <item2 translate="title">
                                <title>List Action</title>
                                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            </item2>
                        </children>
                    </menu1>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sd_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_menu_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="sd_menu/adminhtml_menu" name="menu"/>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_menu_index>
</layout>
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

**app/etc/modules/Sd_Menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sd_Menu>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Sd_Menu>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/sql/sd_menu_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0**

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
Mage::log('START SCRIPT install sd_menu 0.1.0');

try {
    $this->run("
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wlc_sd_menu` (
          `entity_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `name` text NOT NULL,
          `photo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
          `position` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
          `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
          `facebook` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
          `twitter` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
          `linkedin` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
          `instagram` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
          `google_plus` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
          `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
            PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    ");
    Mage::log("Script OK!");
} catch (Exception $e) { Mage::log('Script KO: '.$e); }


Mage::log('END SCRIPT install sd_menu 0.1.0');
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: `app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml.Menu.php` OR   `app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml/Menu.php` ?

Comment: it's `app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml/Menu.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some things you are missing in your module:
in `config.xml` under the `models->menu` tag you need this `<resourceModel>menu_resource</resourceModel>`.

You need the resource model class `/Sd/Menu/Model/Resource/Menu.php`

```
<?php

class Sd_Menu_Model_Resource_Menu extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('menu/menu', 'entity_id');
    }
}
```

and the resource collection model `Sd/Menu/Model/Resource/Menu/Collection.php`

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Model_Resource_Menu_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('menu/menu');
    }
}
```

Also there is no install script that should create your table `Sd/Menu/sql/menu_setup/install-0.1.0.php`

```
<?php
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('menu/menu'))
    ->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
    ), 'Menu ID')
    ->addColumn('name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Menu name')
    ->addColumn('content', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '2M', array(
    ), 'Menu Content')
    ->addColumn('creation_time', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
    ), 'Menu Creation Time')
    ->addColumn('update_time', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
    ), 'Menu Modification Time')
    ->setComment('Menu Table');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
```

You may need to add more columns to the table. I just guessed what you have in it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Marius, I just added what you had written to me i cleared caches and i have the same problem, about the script install I already had it and I forgot to put it. Look at my edit please

Comment: I just recreated your module with the additions I mentioned and I got proper grid.

Comment: It's incredible, I have exactly the same module,  at logs level I have a warning `ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 32: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found`  but I don't think that it comes from this module, even by disabling this module it appears, I just haven't had time to fixe it. I also note that when I click on submenu 2, I lose a container grid (the buttons)

Comment: I was mistaken about the positioning of the resource like the answer of John Thank you @Marius

Answer (score 2):

To addition to Marius's [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/172193/23825), now there is only one mistake in your code.
You have placed `resourceModel` tag in your **config.xml** in wrong location

```
<models>
    <menu>
        <class>Sd_Menu_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>menu_resource</resourceModel> <!-- ADD RESOURCE MODEL HERE -->
    </menu>
    <!-- <resourceModel>menu_resource</resourceModel> REMOVE THIS -->
    <menu_resource>
        <class>Sd_Menu_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <menu>
                <table>wlc_sd_menu</table>
            </menu>
        </entities>
    </menu_resource>
</models>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, do you know why when i click on submenu2 i lose a container grid(buttons)

Answer (score 1):

Below is the corrected code for the entire module (for menu1). I have tested and verified. (In front of each file I have mentioned whether it has been newly added or modified or not)

> app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml/Menu/Grid.php (**Modified**)

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Block_Adminhtml_Menu_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('menuGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('sd_menu/menu')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
            'header'    => $this->__('Id'),
            'align'     =>'right',
            'width'     => '10px',
            'index'     => 'entity_id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header'    => $this->__('Name'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'name',
            'width'     => '50px',
        ));


        $this->addColumn('address', array(
            'header'    => $this->__('Address'),
            'width'     => '150px',
            'index'     => 'content',
        ));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

> app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml/Menu.php (**Not modified**)

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Block_Adminhtml_Menu extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup     = 'sd_menu';
        $this->_controller     = 'adminhtml_menu';
        $this->_headerText     = $this->__('Gérer le Menu');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = $this->__('Ajouter');
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

> app/code/local/Sd/Menu/controllers/Adminhtml/MenuController.php (**Not
>   modified**)

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Adminhtml_MenuController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('Menu 1')
            ->_title($this->__('Submenu1')); // for title
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function listAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('Menu 1')
            ->_title($this->__('Submenu2')); //for title
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Sd/Menu/etc/adminhtml.xml (**Not modified**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <menu1 module="sd_menu" translate="title">
            <title>Menu 1</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <item1 module="sd_menu" translate="title">
                    <title>Submenu 1</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/menu/index</action>
                </item1>
                <item2 module="sd_menu" translate="title">
                    <title>Submenu 2</title>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/menu/list</action>
                </item2>
            </children>
        </menu1>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <menu1 translate="title" module="sd_menu">
                        <title>My Controller</title>
                        <sort_order>-100</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <item1 translate="title">
                                <title>Index Action</title>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            </item1>
                            <item2 translate="title">
                                <title>List Action</title>
                                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            </item2>
                        </children>
                    </menu1>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Sd/Menu/etc/config.xml (**Modified**)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sd_Menu>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Sd_Menu>
    </modules>
    <global>

        <helpers>
            <sd_menu>
                <class>Sd_Menu_Helper</class>
            </sd_menu>
        </helpers>

        <blocks>
            <sd_menu>
                <class>Sd_Menu_Block</class>
            </sd_menu>
        </blocks>

        <models>
            <sd_menu>
                <class>Sd_Menu_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>sd_menu_resource</resourceModel>
            </sd_menu>
            <sd_menu_resource>
                <class>Sd_Menu_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <menu>
                        <table>wlc_sd_menu</table>
                    </menu>
                </entities>
            </sd_menu_resource>
        </models>

        <resources>
            <sd_menu_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Sd_Menu</module>
                </setup>
            </sd_menu_setup>
        </resources>

    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <sd_menu before="Mage_Adminhtml">Sd_Menu_Adminhtml</sd_menu>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <sd_menu>
                    <file>sd_menu.xml</file>
                </sd_menu>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Helper/Data.php (**Not modified**)

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
```

{

```
}
```

> app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Model/Resource/Menu/Collection.php (**Newly
>   Added**)

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Model_Resource_Menu_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('sd_menu/menu');
    }
}
```

> app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Model/Resource/Menu.php (**Newly Added**)

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Model_Resource_Menu extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('sd_menu/menu', 'entity_id');
    }
}
```

> app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Model/Menu.php (**Modified**)

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Model_Menu extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('sd_menu/menu');
    }
}
```

> app/code/local/Sd/Menu/sql/sd_menu_setup/install-0.1.0.php (N**ewly
>   Added**)

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('sd_menu/menu'))
    ->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
    ), 'Id')
    ->addColumn('name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Name')
    ->addColumn('address', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
    ), 'Address');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$installer->endSetup();
```

> app/etc/modules/Sd_Menu.xml (Not modified)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sd_Menu>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Sd_Menu>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sd_menu.xml (**Not modified**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_menu_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="sd_menu/adminhtml_menu" name="menu"/>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_menu_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, do you know why when i click on submenu2 i lose a container grid(buttons)

Comment: You have to create separate container classes and relevant grid class as you did for the submenu1